# Clearing a form with useReducer and additional reducers

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, state-management

I don't know if I just don't understand Redux State Management or if it's something else.

**The idea**
I have a component which creates a new document with the data provided in a form.
This component calls an action to make the api request.
If successful, the action dispatches a reducer to show a snackbar/message.
It should also delete all entries in the form field.

**Current Situation**
I can enter data into my form and the "jobFormData" inside the state get updated as expected.
When I hit submit the data from "jobFormData" are send to the api, as it should.
The "jobSuccess" state gets set to  "true" and I can see the snackbar.

**Problem**
The form fields don't reset after a successful request.

My understanding is that "formState" gets/is the state in "jobReducer".
Therefore "formState" should react to "jobFormData". I set "jobFormData" to empty, but the form fields keep their values?

**My questions**

1. How can I clear the fields after a successful request
2. Is the workflow displayed here correct or am I missusing/ missunderstanding redux?

**Project structure**

```
import jobReducer from './../../../reducers/jobReducer';
import { createJob } from '../../../actions/dataAction';
...
export default function JobCreate() {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   ...
    // snackbar
    const openSnackbar = useSelector(state => state.job).jobSuccess;
    
    // formstate for the form using a reducer and not multiple useStates
    const formState = useSelector(state => state.job).jobFormData;
    
    // update the values of the form
    let onChange = event => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'UPDATE_JOB_FORM',
            field: event.target.id,
            payload: event.target.value
        })
    };

    // dispatch the action to make the api request and clear the form
    let onSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createJob(formState));
    };


    return(
       ...
       <form className={classes.form} noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
         <TextField
         className={classes.textInput}
         required
         id="title"
         label="Einsatz Titel"
         variant="outlined"
         onChange={onChange}
         value={formState.title}
         />
        ....
```

JobCreator.js

```
export const createJob = (params) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await api.createJob(params);
        dispatch({
            type: 'CREATE_JOB',
            payload: { success: true, data: {} }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

dataAction.js

```
const job = (state = { jobData: {}, jobFormData: {} }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_JOB':
            return { ...state, jobFormData: action?.payload.data, jobSuccess: action?.payload.success };
        case 'UPDATE_JOB_FORM':
            return { ...state, jobFormData: { ...state.jobFormData, [action.field]: action?.payload } };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default job;
```

jobReducer.js

Any idea is appreciated :D

Comment: Im very confused with this code, you are mixing Redux actions with `useReducer` actions, without a reproducible example can't guess what is going on here. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash thanks for the comment, I updated the code so I hope it's easier to follow now. I removed the useReducer and just added a useSelector instead. But the problem still exists

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's hard to follow, hope you will get an answer, good luck.

Comment: It looks like you are resetting it when handling `CREATE_JOB` as you set jobFormData to an empty object. I wonder if the issue is more related to not having 'controlled' react inputs in your form meaning the input data isn't two-way?

Comment: It looks correct at a first glance.  It might help if you could create a CodeSandbox or something that's interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.
The problem was that the state in the Reducer was like the following:

*Init:*

```
jobFormData: {}
```

The TextField is looking for "jobFormData.title". Since it doesn't exist, the TextField is an uncontrolled component.

*While editing the form, the values change to something like this:*

```
jobFormData:{title: 'cool title'}
```

This breaks Reacts logic by making the TextField a controlled component (controlled by jobFormData.title).

*After the successfull update:*

```
jobFormData: {}
```

jobFormData becomes an empty object and therefore "jobFormData.title" no longer exists and the TextField component becomes uncontrolled again.

**Solution**
make the inital state already containing the desired form fields. This will make the component controlled the whole time and therefore allows the developer to manipulate it.

```
const job = (state = { jobData: {}, formData: { title: '', department: '', description: '', postcode: '' } }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_JOB':
            return { ...state, formData: action?.payload.data, jobSuccess: action?.payload.success };
        case 'UPDATE_JOB_FORM':
            return { ...state, formData: { ...state.formData, [action.field]: action?.payload } };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default job;
```

jobReducer.js

```
export const createJob = (params) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await api.createJob(params);
        dispatch({
            type: 'CREATE_JOB',
            payload: { success: true, data: {title:''} }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

dataAction.js